# Does the preposition 'of' sound redundant in my sentences?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Does the preposition 'of' sound redundant in the following sentences:

> - Our forces **destroyed two *of***  enemy planes yesterday.
> - Our forces **knocked out two *of*** enemy plans yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The word "of" is not simply redundant; it is incorrect. Either you can, as you suggest, remove "of":

> - Our forces destroyed two enemy planes yesterday.

Alternatively you could add a "the":

> - Our forces destroyed two of the enemy planes yesterday.

There is a subtle difference in meaning between the two. For instance, I would say that the second version suggests that the enemy had more than two planes before two of them were destroyed.

Comment: what about the second sentence "knocked out"?

Comment: A-friend - _knocked out_ is simply jargon for _shot down_ or _destroyed_. It can be used.